# CSS different transition easing when adding or removing class

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

Is it possible for a CSS transition to ease-in when the class is added and ease-out when it's removed?

```js
$('button').on("click", function(){
  $('.box').toggleClass("alt")
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  transition: all 1500ms cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);

  /* easeOutCubic cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1); */
  /* easeInCubic cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19); */
}

.box.alt {
  transform: translate3d(600px, 0px, 0) scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add transition to the alt class also

```
.box.alt {
    transition: all 1500ms cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19); // added ease in transition as mentioned by you in ques
    transform: translate3d(600px, 0px, 0) scale(1.5);
}
```